# in a console app what's the best way to prevent special sequences in command line arguments from being escaped?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, console-application, command-line-arguments

I wrote this console app that reads a sequence of command line arguments and does something with them.

The problem is that if the user enters something like:

```
 --folder "C:\my folder\" --username john
```

the args String array of the Main function will have 2 elements rather than 4:

```
1st element: "--folder"
2nd element: "C:\my folder\" --username john"
```

(the \" sequence is escaped as a double quote.)

Since not using quotes would result in 5 elements...

```
--folder C:\my folder\ --username john

1st element: --folder
2nd element: C:\my
3rd element: folder\
4th element: --username
5th element: john
```

... what's the best way to get around this problem?

Comment: Um. If someone is incorrectly escaping the arguments they're providing on the command line, they should fix it when they're typing on the command line. It's not something you should try and fix (using some form of "best guessing" at what the user intended) inside the program.

Comment: There's an article over on CodeProject [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3111/C-NET-Command-Line-Arguments-Parser) about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a consequence of the weird command line parsing rules on Windows.  See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/17w5ykft(v=vs.85).aspx.  The command line should actually be: `--folder "C:\my folder\\" --username john`

This is a user input error.  You shouldn't try to correct it code; just fail gracefully.